# Dismiss View Controller after Google Sign In calls methods in App Delegate (iOS / Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented Google Sign in on my project, where I have a View Controller for handling logins that is presented modally. The google sign in button calls methods that are in the app delegate.

I want to be able to dismiss the View Controller once the user has signed in, but I'm stuck on how to do this. 
Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6zRh.png

dismiss() can't be called from the app delegate. I tried putting a function in my login view controller that checks if the user is logged in, but this doesn't run as the login process is run async (not to mention a very hacky method)

```
//Code on the Login VC:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Google Sign in stuff

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    // Automatically sign in the user.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
    ...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

...

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

...

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {

    let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    let facebookDidHandle = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    return facebookDidHandle || googleDidHandle
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
            print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return
    }
    guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { fatalError("couldn't get idToken")}// Safe to send to the server

    googleSignIn(idToken: idToken)
}
```

...

Once the user is signed in, I'd like to close the modally presented view controller, but I don't know how to do that from the app delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set uiDelegate to get information about google sign-in controller present or dismiss.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
```

And then need to implement `GIDSignInUIDelegate` in your class.

```
extension ViewController: GIDSignInUIDelegate {

//MARK: GoogleSignIn UI Delegate

public func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {
}

public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                 present viewController: UIViewController!) {
}

public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                 dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Using these methods you can dismiss your `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

When the user taps Sign in with Google button. You can call the below method.

```
@objc func didTapGooglePlusLoginButton(sender:UIButton)  {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
```

And you can implement GIDSignInDelegate in the Login VC and add the didSignInFor delegate method in the Login VC itself so that you can handle the input and the output.

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController,GIDSignInDelegate
```

You can dismiss or move to another class in the below function

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            print(user.profile)
            let userId = user.userID                  
            self.Name = user.profile.name
            self.givenName = user.profile.givenName
            self.Email = user.profile.email
            let navigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
            appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            // ...dissmiss or move to another controller
        }
        else {
            print("\(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information guys... you put me onto the right track!

Here's my solution for the most current (August 2019) Google Sign In Swift SDK, as there are some minor changes in delegate names and whatnot.

So basically, set the login view controller as a GIDSignInDelegate:

```
class LoginController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate {
```

...

Put the following in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Google Sign in stuff
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "your-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
// Automatically sign in the user.
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
```

...

and implement the following functions in your login view controller (as per the google documentation)

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
  if let error = error {
    if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
      print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
    } else {
      print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return
  }
  // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
  let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
  let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
  let fullName = user.profile.name
  let givenName = user.profile.givenName
  let familyName = user.profile.familyName
  let email = user.profile.email
  // ...
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
  // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed this method to write in the `appdelegate' file. Please check the below method.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        let isGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        return isFB || isGoogle
    }
```

For more google login information, please check out the below link: [Github link](https://gist.github.com/Ilesh/3d25ad031f391fb3d3a80480f6ef76a9) if it helps you then hit start :) so other will find it easily.

Happy codding:)